# for loop to iterate through words

Tags: python, for-loop

My previous post caused a lot of confusion and it flooded with answers that is not relevant to my questions. (My fault for not clarifying things) I flagged that post and this is the new post. 
So basically I would like to do a conjunction of words.

```
EG1

    input [jason, sonny, nyorth]

    output [jason, sonny, nyorth, jasonnyorth]

EG2
    Sample input: [aw, was,poq, qo, soo] 
    Output [aw, was, poq, qo, soo, awasoo, poqo] 


EG3

    input: `[keyboard, ardjimmy]    
    output: `[keyboard, ardjimmy, keyboardjimmy]
```

I am trying to have the output of

```
['jimmy', 'myolita'] 
jimmyolita
['jimmy', 'myolita', 'jimmyolita']

['myolita', 'jimmy']
jimmyolita
['myolita', 'jimmy', 'jimmyolita']
```

I know it's a double for loop but I just keep getting super weird stuff. I want to keep my post simple so I am not posting my attempts S=. On the side note I also dislike the way I do the "check" and "maxNum" thing, I have a feeling that it doesn't cover all case and gives me weird output for certain specific case. I prefer to do it in for loop because there are other part of the questions that is not listed in here. One example is when there's an infinite case:

```
[abc, bca] -> [abc, ca, abca] -> [abc, ca, abca, abcabc] -> it will keep going.



testing = ["jimmy", "myolita"]

testing1 = ["myolita", "jimmy"]
def frags(strings):
    check = 1
    maxNum = 1
    for i in range(0,len(strings[1])):
        if strings[0].find(strings[1][:i]) > maxNum:
            check = 0
            maxNum = strings[0].find(strings[1][:i])

    if check == 0:
       toReturn = strings[0][:maxNum] + strings[1]
       strings.append(toReturn)
    else:
       toReturn = "no match"

    return toReturn



print(testing)
print(frags(testing))                            
print(testing)

print("   ")

print(testing1)
print(frags(testing1))                            
print(testing1)
```

Comment: First, whoever told you to use flag variables like this just so you could have a single `return` and never use `break` and so on is not your friend. You're right to dislike what the way you do the `check` and `maxNum` thing, but doing that is inherent in sticking to the "one return" rule (which _may_ make sense for pre-C99 C, but definitely not for Python).

Comment: Also, if you've got a list with a fixed size of two elements, split it into two variables: `leftstring, rightstring = strings`. It's a lot easier to read `leftstring.find(rightstring[:i])` than `strings[0].find(strings[1][:i])`.

Comment: what output are you expecting, your examples don't seem to be consistent?

Comment: Hi albarnet. I am new to this, so how would u use break to replace maxNum and check?

Comment: @Jimson: Sorry, I'm not entirely sure what they're supposed to be doing, so… that comment may not have been right. Can you explain your algorithm in human terms (pseudocode), either in general, or for your specific example input?

Comment: I edit my post. The input doesn't have to be 2 words only. I need to use a for loop to iterate through everything.

Comment: In your edited post, I still don't understand what the rule is you're trying to apply. The only explanation you have is "a conjunction of words", and then some code that apparently doesn't do what you want.

Comment: You may need to think through the possible cases for what you are (I think) trying to do ... your example output indicates that you don't want to care about order when splicing your strings together, but what would you want if you have something like `['jimmy','mykanji']`? jimmykanji? mykanjimmy? jimmykan?

Comment: if given [jimmy, mykanji] it should output [jimmy, mykanji, jimmykanji, mykanjimmy]

Comment: Meanwhile, if you can't explain what you want, why not break your problem into two parts, solve the first one, then work on the second. In other words, try to explain how it should work for two words, explain what's wrong with the existing answers, let people help you get it working… and _then_ worry about what you want to do for three or more words, which should be a lot easier to explain (in a new question) when you have working code for two words.

Answer (score 2):

I think your rule goes something like this: If the first string has a suffix that's also a prefix of the second string, chop it off. Then merge the two strings.

If you search backward, starting with the whole string and working down instead of starting with a single character and working up, you don't need to keep track of anything at all, other than the current suffix you're testing. In other words:

```
def frags(strings):
    left, right = strings
    for i in reversed(range(len(left))):
        if right.startswith(left[-i:]):
            return left[:-i] + right
    return left+right
```

Comment: what if you were given [abbbbbbbbbb, bde]? Your function will not return abbbbbbde instead it will only return abbbbbbb bde.

Comment: @Jimson: What makes you think that? `1` is part of `range(len(left))`, and `left[-1:]` is `b`, and `right.startswith('b')`, so it will return `left[:-1] + right`. Just try it and see.

Answer (score 0):

String slicing will likely make the code *much* simpler.  Here's something to get you started:

```
def overlap(left, right):
    for i in reversed(range(len(left))):
            if left[-i:] == right[:i]:
                break
    return left + right[i:]

for pair in [
    ('keyboard', 'ardjimmy'),
    ('jimmy', 'myolita'),
    ('myolita', 'jimmy'),
]:
    left, right = pair
    print pair, '-->', overlap(left, right), overlap(right, left)
```

Comment: i edit my post. The input doesn't have to be 2 words only. I need to use a for loop to iterate through everything.