# Fragment words combination

Tags: python, recursion

I would like to do a conjunction of words where

```
EG1

    input [jason, sonny, nyorth]

    output [jason, sonny, nyorth, jasonnyorth]

EG2
    Sample input: [aw, was,poq, qo, soo] 
    Output [aw, was, poq, qo, soo, awasoo, poqo] 


EG3

    input: [keyboard, ardjimmy]    
    output:[keyboard, ardjimmy, keyboardjimmy]
```

My code is shown below. There's 3 things that I would like to improve on.

1. I don't want to use check and maxNum. I feel like there will be some cases where the 2 variables will cause an error. It also feels like bad programming.
2. My function is not doing exactly what it meant to do. Meaning, if I am given [abb, bba] my function outputs [abb, bba, abba, bbabb] instead of [abb, bba, abbba, bbabb]
3. Lastly, my function does not recurse itself. For example: given the input [ab, ba] the output should be
   [ab, ba, aba, bab] then it should recurse and become [ab, ba, aba, bab, abab, baba] it will keep going to infinity. When I encounter an infinite loop I should handle that but I'm not even close to solving this problem as of yet.

For 1) I am not sure how I am going to replace it with. For 3) I haven't even solve 1) and 2) I don't want to make my function recurse itself. It will get all sorts of weird errors. I want to keep my post clean for revision. Also I will bump into unnecessary duplicates if I do recursion. I would appreciate if someone can enlighten me on 3). For now my priority is 1) and 2).

```
  #testing = ["jimmy", "myolita", "paizuri", "mybaby"]
testing = ["ca","abc"]

testing1 = ["mybaby", "myolita", "jimmy", "paizuri"]
def frags(strings):
    check = 1
    maxNum = 0
    length = len(strings)
    for x in range(0,length):
        for y in range(0,length):
            if x != y:                
                for i in range(0,len(strings[y])):
                    if strings[x].find(strings[y][:i]) > maxNum:
                        check = 0
                        maxNum = strings[x].find(strings[y][:i])

                if check == 0:
                   toReturn = strings[x][:maxNum] + strings[y]
                   strings.append(toReturn)
                   check = 1
                   maxNum = 0
    return strings



print(testing)
print(frags(testing))                            


print("   ")

print(testing1)
print(frags(testing1))
```

Comment: Anyone have any ideas on it?

Comment: You have already asked [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25213658/for-loop-to-iterate-through-words) -- do not ask it again.

Comment: That post has been flagged by me. The answers I got is not what I wanted so i repost it. I already explained it S=.

Comment: Interesting problem. Just to further clarify the question, what would be the corresponding outputs for the inputs ['a'] and ['a', 'a']?

Comment: ['a'] nothing. ['a','a'] will blowup the function and I need to handle that in 3)

Comment: One more question, if you had ['abb', 'bba'], would you end up adding 'abba' or 'abbba' or both? I guess what I am asking is, when combining strings, are you always looking for the maximum matching sub-string?

Comment: yes, we are looing for maximum matching sub-string. so it will be abbba. I edited my post. Interesting case you got there. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For the recursion issue you can go brute force and start your own object instead of getting your pointer associated with the original list, i.e.

```
list_a = ["cat", "dog", "mouse"]

new_list = [i for i in list_a]
```

or

```
new_list = []
new_list.append(list_a[0])
...
newlist.append(list_a[0] + list_a[2])
```

Comment: Welcome new user!  As a tip, you can put that code into a code block for easier reading.  Also, anything you post will probably be better received if you try to use real words, instead of shorthand. ("ur")

Comment: Any commments on 1) and 2)?

Comment: Thanks Ajean! First post.